# Migrating from Eclipse ADT to Android Studio 2.2

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

So my project structure looks like this:

```
Applications/Project1/Build/Android/AndroidManifest.xml
Applications/Project2/Build/Android/AndroidManifest.xml
Common/Library1/Build/Android/AndroidManifest.xml
```

Note that beside `AndroidManifest.xml` are the other usual directories and files, such as `.project`, `jni` directory, `src` directory, and so on.

I want to import these as Android Studio projects, however when I do that it reorganizes the structure, in addition it doesn't seem to do the upgrade in-place, when I want it to. What I get instead is this structure:

```
Project1/build.gradle
Project2/build.gradle
Library1/build.gradle
```

To make things worse, it also copied my physical source files and recognized those as well. Is there an easier way to transition to Android Studio, while at the same time keeping the existing structure as close as possible? I also don't want the upgrade to happen in a remote location. I want this to physically replace the current Eclipse and Ant project files. Should I do this by hand? Or is there some trick I can use in Android Studio's import wizard?

Also: Not sure if it matters, but the code base is primarily C++ + CMake. Current projects use Android.mk, but I'd want to make them use the CMake scripts instead. However, if that doesn't bear any affect on this process we can ignore it and I'm happy to address the C++/CMake integration later as a separate step. Right now I just want the general projects to get setup, have proper Gradle scripts, and other things (Java side, basically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest doing it by hand. It could be faster than getting to make the tool do the right thing.

Remember that migration/import tools are much more rarely used tools than, say "call hierarchy" or "find usages" and thus they might get less love and polish.

Writing gradle files by hand is actually quite fast. The syntax is quite light (unlike, say, Maven, or worse, Ant).

Try it and you might find Gradle to become a friend, rather than "foe" ;).

Also, don't forget `settings.gradle` to tie the modules together.

Another suggestion would be to trick the import tool via making a project with simpler structure and then copy&paste the relevant bits into your own structure (so that you more-or-less know what to put in your gradle files).

Comment: Sure, I think I will do this. Android Studio actually created several files with XML content in them. I think one had the extension `iml`. Are these necessary or just the `.gradle` files?